# using phpmailer with google apps

Tags: php, email, google-apps

can anyone help me figure out what the problem is here. I've done lots of searches and have done what I've found to no success.

here is my error, phpmailer is newest version

---

```
2015-08-08 13:15:03 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.mysite.com:465, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2015-08-08 13:15:04    SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) 2015-08-08 13:15:04   SMTP connect() failed.
```

here is my code.

```
$m = new PHPMailer;
//Setup
$m->isSMTP();
$m->SMTPAuth = true;
//authentication
$m->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$m->Username = 'info@example.com';
$m->Password = 'password';
$m->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$m->Port = 465;
$m->SMTPDebug  = 3;    
//from
$m->AddReplyTo($email, $name);
$m->SetFrom('info@example.com', $name);
//to
$m->addAddress('ari@example.com','guy johnson');
$m->addCC('joe@example.com','Joe johnson');
//message
$m->Subject = $subject;
$m->Body = $message;


if(!$m->Send()) {
echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
                "alert('A Error Occured, Please Try Again.');".
                "</script>";
} else {
echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
                "alert('Message Sent. Please allow atleast 24-hours for a response');".
                "window.location='http://example.com';".
                "</script>";
}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the port is correct?

Comment: @ajon thats what it says to put everywhere i have looked.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message shows smtp.example.com in the error but your code shows smtp.gmail.com.  Have you tried port 25?  The Google documentation suggests trying that with SSL.

Comment: 1) yes ive tried all 3 ports. 2) smtp.gmail.com is gmails server for mail and/or google apps meaning example.com is my google apps email. (this is the correct code) 3) this should have been posted as a comment not an answer.